# class attribute within own class

Tags: python, class, attributes

I would like to have a class instance as a class attribute within its own class. It is to organize a fixed set of instances of that class. I think I have done this in Java some time ago.

Calling

```py
c = A()
```

outside of the class works perfectly.

Minimal code example:

```py
class A:
    c = A()
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = 1
    def doSomething(self):
        print(self.B)
```

But there is always a Error: NameError: name 'A' is not defined

```py
----> 2     c = A()
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

Is it possible to have 'c' as a instance of the class A?
Then I would call it with:

```py
A.c.doSomething()
```

etc.
Of course in the real code there are more instances like 'c'.

Comment: If there are *more instances like c* it feels like a bad idea to put them inside (or add them to) the class. Why not just have a list of those instances, outside the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but you have to finish defining the class first, before you can instantiate it.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = 1

    def doSomething(self):
        print(self.B)

A.c = A()
```

---

A `class` statement provides a more declarative approach to creating a class than calling `type` explicitly. The above is equivalent to

```
def A_init(self):
    self.B = 1

def A_doSomething(self):
    print(self.B)

A = type("A", (), {'__init__': A_init, 'doSomething': A_doSomething})
del A_init, A_doSomething
```

The call to `type` has to complete before you can add instances of `A` to the `dict` passed as the third argument to `type`.

---

You might find a decorator makes the addition of the class attributes more "atomic":

```
def add_instances(*names):
    def _(cls):
        for name in names:
            setattr(cls, name, cls())
        return cls
    return _

@add_instances("c", "d", "e")
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = 1

    def doSomething(self):
        print(self.B)
```

will result in `A.c`, `A.d`, and `A.e` all referring to distinct instances of `A`. Note that `add_instances` doesn't make any assumptions about the class it is applied to, other than assuming it can be instantiated without any arguments.

---

In case you are wondering why you can write a recursive function by referring to the function you are currently defining:

```
def factorial(n):
    return 1 if n == 0 else n*factorial(n-1)
```

the difference is that the body of a `def` statement is only *parsed*, not evaluated, when the `def` statement itself is evaluated. The body of a `class` statement is *evaluated*, statement by statement, in order to produce a `dict` which is passed to `type`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help. I found another approach that works:

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def initiate_instances():
        A.c = A()

    def __init__(self):
        self.B = 1

    def doSomething(self):
        print(self.B)

A.initiate_instances()
A.c.doSomething()
```